# Adding a block to CMS page is not working

Tags: cms-block

I am trying to add a new block to the CMS home page. Only this particular block I need to do it in the content tab, and not the layout tab( which works).

So in the content tab I have(Does not work):

```
{{block type="dailydeal/list" name="product_list_deals" template="dailydeal/slider.phtml" }}
```

But if I do it in the layout tab(Works fine):

```
<reference name="content">
            <block type="dailydeal/list" name="product_list" after="home_slider_cruisercorps" template="dailydeal/slider.phtml" />               
</reference>
```

I am not sure what is missing in the content tab, causing the block not to be loaded.

Using magento version 1.9.2.4

Comment: Allow block in `dailydeal/list` in admin-> system-> permission->blocks->add new block -> Enter `dailydeal/list` in `Block name`  and `Yes` in `Is Allowed` it should resolve your issue.

Comment: Let me know if its help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Allow block in dailydeal/list in admin-> system-> permission->blocks->add new block -> Enter dailydeal/list in Block name and Yes in Is Allowed it should resolve your issue.